# An internal error occurred during: "Acceleo" on fresh install

Tags: eclipse, acceleo

After fresh Eclipse install (Windows 10, 64bit, JRE 1.8.0_181-b13) I installed   Acceleo    3.7.7.201812041426. But after creating new project (2002/ecore with "Generate file" and "Main template") it fails creating sceleton mtl and java files with error

```
An internal error occurred during: "Acceleo".
```

with exception

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageImpl.eObjectForURIFragmentNameSegment(EPackageImpl.java:1970)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EModelElementImpl.eObjectForURIFragmentSegment(EModelElementImpl.java:473)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.getEObject(ResourceImpl.java:811)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.getEObject(ResourceImpl.java:787)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.setValueFromId(XMLHandler.java:2868)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.setAttribValue(XMLHandler.java:2773)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.SAXXMIHandler.handleObjectAttribs(SAXXMIHandler.java:79)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectFromFactory(XMLHandler.java:2247)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectFromTypeName(XMLHandler.java:2150)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObject(XMLHandler.java:2085)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.createObject(XMIHandler.java:151)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.handleFeature(XMLHandler.java:1868)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.processElement(XMLHandler.java:1048)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.processElement(XMIHandler.java:82)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:1026)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:720)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.startElement(XMIHandler.java:190)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:175)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:261)
at org.eclipse.acceleo.model.mtl.resource.EMtlResourceImpl.doLoad(EMtlResourceImpl.java:93)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1563)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:259)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:274)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:406)
at org.eclipse.acceleo.common.utils.ModelUtils.load(ModelUtils.java:391)
at org.eclipse.acceleo.common.utils.ModelUtils.load(ModelUtils.java:356)
at org.eclipse.acceleo.ide.ui.resources.AcceleoProject.loadAllPlatformOutputFiles(AcceleoProject.java:737)
at org.eclipse.acceleo.ide.ui.resources.AcceleoProject.loadNotAccessibleOutputFiles(AcceleoProject.java:680)
at org.eclipse.acceleo.internal.ide.ui.views.overrides.OverridesBrowser.updateViewTemplates(OverridesBrowser.java:340)
at org.eclipse.acceleo.internal.ide.ui.views.overrides.OverridesBrowser$3.run(OverridesBrowser.java:315)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I have tried several times with new eclipse setups but failed every time. Is this Acceleo bug?